# Set an int pointer to an int value in Go

Tags: pointers, go

I'm very new to Go and am trying to set a `*int` to point to a number, say `12345`.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    var guess *int
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(guess))
    *guess = 12345
    fmt.Println(guess)
}
```

But it's giving me the following error:

```
Type: *int
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x483c7d]

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
    /home/aaron/projects/gopath/src/github.com/AaronNBrock/go-guess/main.go:16 +0x9d
exit status 2
```

I see that the error is with the `*guess = 12345` since `12345`, but I'm not sure what's causing it.

Comment: Refresh your knowledge about pointer in the Tour of Go, maybe starting from https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/1

Comment: @Volker I went through the tour before asking the question but it didn't appear to address the case of setting a pointer to a value directly.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You have a pointer variable which after declaration will be `nil`.

If you want to set the pointed value, it must point to something. Attempting to dereference a `nil` pointer is a runtime panic, just what you experienced. You may use the builtin [`new()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#new) function to obtain a pointer to a zero-valued `int`, and then you can set the pointed value:

```
var guess *int
guess = new(int)
*guess = 12345
```

Your modified app:

```
var guess *int
fmt.Println(guess)
guess = new(int)
*guess = 12345
fmt.Println(guess, *guess)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/uNtN6O2hoAi)):

```
<nil>
0x10414028 12345
```

Note that you can make this shorter using a [short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations) like this:

```
guess := new(int)
*guess = 12345
```

Another option to make a pointer point to something "useful" is to assign the address of a variable to the pointer variable, like this:

```
value := 12345 // will be of type int
guess := &value
```

But this solution modifies the pointer value, not the pointed value. The result is the same though in this simple example.

You could also just assign the address of another variable, and then proceed to change the pointed value:

```
var value int
guess := &value
*guess = 12345
```

Also note that since `guess` points to `value`, changing the pointed value will change the value of the `value` variable too. Also if you change the `value` variable directly, the pointed value by `guess` also changes: they are one and the same:

```
var value int
guess := &value
value = 12345
fmt.Println(*guess) // This will also print 12345
```

Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/54e3FwohGRB).

Answer (score 6):

Here's one possible utility function:

```
func getIntPointer(val int) *int {
    return &val
}
```

Or as an inline anonymous function:

```
func(val int) *int { return &val }(val)
```

For example,

```
var foo *int = func(val int) *int { return &val }(10)
```

[Run on *The Go Playground*](https://play.golang.org/p/okjdWzTLnQy)

EDIT: It's probably better to make this a 2-liner:

```
val := new(int)
*val = 5
```

Answer (score 4):

FWIW, if you do this often enough (like setting up data in unit tests) it's useful to have a shorthand, hence:

https://github.com/mwielbut/pointy

```golang
val := 42
pointerToVal := &val
// vs.
pointerToVal := pointy.Int(42)
```

Comment: I actually searched this question looking for a built-in like this.  Nice.

Answer (score 4):

Starting from Go 1.18 you can make use of generics

```golang
func Pointer[K any](val K) *K {
    return &val
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you really want an int pointer and not just an int, then you need a variable to store the `int` you point to. For example:

```
var guess *int
a := 12345
guess = &a
```

Answer (score 3):

A tricky way to get int pointer without create new variable.

```golang
someIntPtr := &[]int64{10}[0]
```

Like this, you don't have to use a one line func like `func(val int) *int { return &val }(10)` or create a variable of int.